# Django - accessing the pk/id of Post module that is inside a Comment model

Tags: django

So i have this post module:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(timezone.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-home')
```

and this comment module:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=255)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-home')
```

and this is my view for the comment:

```
class CreateComment(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'my_blog/create_post.html'
    fields = ['content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.comment_author = self.request.user
        # form.instance.post_id =
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

as for the urls:

/post/1  ===> will be post number 1

/post/1/comment ===> is the form the to post a new comment

I want the form.instance.post_id to be the post id that the comment belongs to.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
```

was the thing i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have a url pattern similar to this:

```
path('post/<int:pk>/comment', CreateComment.as_view(), name='create_comment')
```

Here's what I would do (assuming SingleObjectMixin works in combination with CreateView):

```
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin

class CreateComment(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView, SingleObjectMixin):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'my_blog/create_post.html'
    fields = ['content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.comment_author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = self.get_object()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```